# invalid cast from type ‘CvSeq’ to type ‘CvPoint* (How to typecast in Opencv)

Tags: c++, opencv

i get the error at line below

Vertex2 = (CvPoint*)Vertices[I]; //where **vertices is cvseq** of contour and **Vertex2 is cvpoint**

i get error  invalid cast from type ‘CvSeq’ to type ‘CvPoint*

how do i solve this

Comment: Please show enough of the code to help us figure out the problem - in this case, include the declarations of Vertex2 and Vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to get the address of the element in the array? in which case you would go

```
cvseq* Vertex2 = &Vertices[i];
```

A pointer called Vertex2 of type cvseq pointer whose value is the address of element i in the array Vertices.

**UPDATE:**

Just to help you know exactly what is wrong with your code.

```
'CvSeq' to type 'CvPoint*'
```

This is saying the you have a varaible of type CvPoint* (that would be your Vertex2) and you are trying to assign data of the type CvSeq.

Comment: Hai Vertex2 is of CVPoint and Vertices is of Cvseq type its not working with a bove it says 
cannot convert ‘CvSeq*’ to ‘CvPoint*’ in initialization

Comment: with the line of code I have? Are you later trying to use Vertex2 for a function that likes to take a Cvpoint* ? what is the difference between cvseq and cvpoint? You can't alway cast from one type to another. it works for things like casting a float to an int to cut the decimal part, but trying to cast say a 'cat' to a 'flower' is too complex. to cast 'cat' to a 'flower' you would need to extend class cat to have a function that returns it data in the format of an instance of type 'flower'

Comment: My code looks like this
        else
        {
         Vertex2 = (CvPoint*)Vertices[I];//here is the error i get
            if(I<Vertices->total-1)  
            {
                 Vertex3 = (CvPoint)Vertices[I + 1];
                 if (Vertex3.X == -1 && Vertex3.Y == -1)                                               
               // Check vertex k if it is start of a curve
                {
                     Vertex3 = (CvPoint)Vertices[I + 2];
                     curve = true;
                }

Comment: am i clear i am not able to post whole code but at first line i get the error after changing it says "convert ‘CvSeq*’ to ‘CvPoint*’ in initialization"

Comment: Don't forget that you can edit you 'question' to help explain things better. I assume that this code is in a loop of some sort. "Vertex2 = (CvPoint*)Vertices[I];" this line is getting Vertices[i] and type casting it to a point to a CvPoint. This is assuming then the Vertex2 is actaully of type Cvpoint*, but your error says it can't convert CvPoint* to CvSeq* meaning, Vertex* is of type Cvseq*. thus that is what you should be typecasting to, or you should change the definition of Vertex2. your probably don't need to be typecasting or using pointers. You would use points so that you use less RAM