# How do i typecast cvseq to cvpoint

Tags: c++, opencv

Hai ,

how do i typecast in opencv ,I want to type cast to cvseq to cvpoint

Comment: Please post relevant code. Why do you want to cast them. These types seem to mean quite different things.

Comment: I swear I saw this exact same question just the other day.

Comment: @thecoshman You're correct: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536426/invalid-cast-from-type-cvseq-to-type-cvpoint-how-to-typecast-in-opencv

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536426/invalid-cast-from-type-cvseq-to-type-cvpoint-how-to-typecast-in-opencv

Answer (score 4):

From what I can see here:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/dynamic_structures.html

`CvSeq` seems to be some form of data container and can not be directly cast to a `CvPoint`.

This *might* be what you want:

`char* cvGetSeqElem(const CvSeq*  seq, int index)`

I guess it's used like this:

```
CvPoint* point = reinterpret_cast<CvPoint*>(cvGetSeqElem(sequence, some_index));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't typecast in ***onpenCV*** as such, its a feature of C++

you do it something like this

```
float var_a = 9.99;
int   var_b = static_cast<int>var_a;
```

if you had only tried to write

```
int var_b = var_a;
```

You would have got a warning that you can't implicitly (automatically) convert a float to an int, as you lose the decimal.

typecasting (putting the type you KNOW you want in brackets) tells the compiler you know what you are doing and are cool with it.

Comment: whether or not you actually wan't and/or can typecast these types is another matter entirely.

Comment: how is this relevant to the question?

Comment: the question is about typecasting, I am showing him an example of how you typecast. What with it being an example I have not used the exact same types he asked about, but it works for any type. I then pointed out in a comment (admittedly probably should have edited answer to include it) that not all types can be converted to one another.